# Google In App Billing Test Purchases not showing in console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

Are test purchases for in app subscriptions supposed to show in the developer console?

I see them in the Order Management page but I don't see them in the Subscriptions Overview page, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if test purchases are not supposed to show.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are seeing the correct behaviour.

The test subscriptions show in the Order Management page with the prefix "Test: "

The test subscriptions are not supposed to show in Subscriptions Overview. Only real subscriptions appear there.